# Android Minimum SDK Issue

Tags: android

I have a function that I need to use, but I need to set my minimum SDK up to 23 in order to use it. Problem is, our application runs on a lot of lower SDK devices out there in the wild. Is there any way I can setup my project to allow me to compile the application while still using a lower minimum SDK target?

[image: Minimum SDK Issue]

Comment: `... minimum SDK target?` Well, `minimumSdkVersion` is something. `targetSdkVersion` is something else. You are a bit confused, my dear.

Comment: Yes... yes you are right... I was a bit confused... Mondays, right?

Comment: No... Friday, currently. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a function that I need to use, but I need to set my minimum SDK up to 23 in order to use it.

You need to set your `compileSdkVersion` to 23.

> Is there any way I can setup my project to allow me to compile the application while still using a lower minimum SDK target?

Set your `minSdkVersion` to whatever you want. Set your `compileSdkVersion` to 23 or higher. Then, make sure that you only call `canDrawOverlays()` on API Level 23+ devices, such as by checking `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT`.

Comment: Thanks... I found the problem. Turns out the issue was between the keyboard and chair.

Comment: I saw a red line, did the whole auto complete thing, but for some reason failed to see the proper solutions in said auto complete block.

Answer (score 1):

Check that the api is 23 or greater before trying to call this function:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
    Settings.canDrawOverlays(this);
} else {
// I don't think you need to do anything, I believe canDrawOverlays is 
//functionally true for older APIs
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you already had a look at the [Supporting Different Platform Versions](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms.html) page?

If you want to use the method `canDrawOverlays(...)` on ALL platforms, then you simply can't: it's only supported in the API starting from version 23. However, if you want to use this api ONLY when the platform version >= 23 (meaning: only on those devices with AT LEAST Marshmallow installed), then you can:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.MARSHMALLOW) {
    Settings.canDrawOverlays(...)
}
```